# Seth account create

Tags: mac

I'm trying to start Sawtooth-Seth in the HyperLedger project.
Following the tutorial, I came across a problem at the account create phase.
It says:

> Error: Problem submitting account creation transaction: 
>   Code    : 18
>   Title   : Validator Disconnected
>   Message : The validator disconnected before sending a response. Try your request again later.

I suspect it may relate to Rust, because I encountered with an error related to Rust and I reinstall it. And now the sawtooth-validator seems to have some problem with the following error message:

> sawtooth-validator | thread '' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Other("TypeError")', src/libcore/result.rs:997:5
>   sawtooth-validator | note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
>   sawtooth-validator | fatal runtime error: failed to initiate panic, error 5

My environment is:
MacOS 10.14.4
Sawtooth-seth v0.2.2
Rustc 1.33.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. it seems to be not a problem to ask here. let me just close it.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site.  I'm not at all familiar with this, so I can't tell you whether it's on-topic, answerable, etc.  But if you're convinced this isn't the right place to ask, you can delete the question yourself.  You should see a delete button at the end of the post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP requested it.